# "Button Tap" gives "An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command." in Appium Android test

Tags: android, selenium, appium, appium-ios, python-appium

I am running the *SELENIUM+JAVA* test for android app with `appium` for the first time. (*WIndows 8.1*)
I copied the id of button from Appium inspector.
I am trying to click the button.

`isDisplayed` returns *true* or `gettext()` is fine
however `loginBtn.tap(1, 1);` on the button gives following error

**On eclipse console**

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error
>   occurred while processing the command.

**on Appium console**

> info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["element:getSize",{"elementId":"2"}]
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"element:getSize","params":{"elementId":"2"}}
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: getSize
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":{"width":540,"height":168}}
>   info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["element:touchDown",{"elementId":"2","x":270,"y":1836}]
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"element:touchDown","params":{"elementId":"2","x":270,"y":1836}}
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: touchDown
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Performing TouchDown using element? true x: 270, y: 1836
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [error] error while invoking method private boolean com.android.uiautomator.core.InteractionController.touchDown(int,int) on object com.android.uiautomator.core.InteractionController@4c33b with parameters [270, 1836] null
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Problem invoking touchDown: java.lang.RuntimeException: error while invoking method private boolean com.android.uiautomator.core.InteractionController.touchDown(int,int) on object com.android.uiautomator.core.InteractionController@4c33b with parameters [270, 1836]
>   info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":13,"value":{"message":"An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.","origValue":"Failed to execute touch event"},"sessionId":"797740b8-3fb1-45ae-b31e-1db9aa3e4513"}
>   info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/797740b8-3fb1-45ae-b31e-1db9aa3e4513/touch/perform 500 256.730 ms - 198 
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"status":13,"value":"Failed to execute touch event"}
>   info: --> DELETE /wd/hub/session/797740b8-3fb1-45ae-b31e-1db9aa3e4513 {}
>   info: Shutting down appium session

Comment: did u manage to get resolve i am also facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

I got it resolved:

```
MobileElement loginBtn=androidDriver.findElementById("com.spotyo.music:id/button_login");
if (loginBtn.isDisplayed()){
    androidDriver.tap(1, loginBtn, 1);      
}
```